# WPF MainWindow differs at runtime from it's expected outcome

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml

I am relatively new to this platform, so forgive me for my lack of professionalism.

I encountered a problem while creating one of my first WPF applications.
I managed to include some buttons in MainWindow and run it, but I spotted some bugs, so I tried to start from the scratch.

I decided to run an empty window, but then i saw the previous "buggy" window at runtime. Since then, no matter what i change in MainWindow.xaml file i get the same old result.

I tried to chceck whether my program compiles, and for what I know it does.

Unfortunately I erased old xaml code responsible for "buggy" window, but I can recall it was something like this.

```xml
<Window x:Class="ProjektPO.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ProjektPO"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Button x:Name="A" Content="B" Click="A_Click"/>
            </Grid>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And the .cs file (almost default)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace ProjektPO
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Logika interakcji dla klasy MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void A_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Program compiles and dispalys old "buggy" Window.

Comment: Well, try restarting VS, then clean your solution, rebuild your solution and see what happens. If that doesn't help, exit VS again, and manually find and remove any bin folders inside your project directory (don't delete your source code! ;-) )

Comment: I tried restarting VS, but it didn't help. Maybe deleting binaries will help.

Comment: Removing binaries, also didn't help.

Comment: Well, run your program again (**NOT** using the debugger). While it is running, look in the task manager for its process and check the path of the executable called. What is the path? Stop the program, and delete the directory with the executable. Then try building the program again. If it still shows old crap, then you still have old crap somewhere in your source code (and it would then probably the best to just completely obliterate your project/solution and start with a completely new project/solution in a different directory, not using _any_ code snippets/files from your current project)

Comment: Wow! When I ran the program in Release mode it displayed right window! Though When I tried the debug mode once again I encountered same old window. The difference in the path is: Project\bin\Release and Project\bin\Debug

Comment: Are you sure you deleted that bin folder? Anyway, probably best to just completely scrap your current project folder, and start anew with a different, new, empty project.

Comment: Now it works. I had to remove old .obj files, and now it works as intended even in Debug mode. Thanks for helping!